# Table with width: 100% inside position: absolute on IE7

Tags: css, width, internet-explorer-7, css-tables

Please look at this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/dyv88/16/

On IE7, if I put width: 100% on a table, inside a div with position:absolute and width unspecified, the table takes over the entire screen.

All more recent browsers, it does not.

Can someone please explain?

And what's the best way to fix this?  Do I just need to specify width on all absolute positioned elements?  Or is there a better fix with some kind of wrapper element?

Comment: May be a dup of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2458731/css-why-an-input-width100-doesnt-expand-in-an-absolute-box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to position absolute, it must be relative to the *first parent* that is positioned. It seems that IE7 doesn't know which parent that is, because you did not specify one.
Do `position: relative` on one of the parents to fix this. Or position the table relative.

I think specifying width on absolute positioned elements is always a good thing, since absolute positioned elements are taken out of the regular low of the page.

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mikey/39bnW/)

Comment: Same results with width if the absolute div's parent is also positioned.

Comment: You also have to specify the child `div` width to 100%. Is this want you want to accomplish?
http://jsfiddle.net/39bnW/1/

Comment: accepting answer for because of comment "width on absolute positioned elements is always a good thing" - that appears to be the issue.

Comment: More explanation: for non-absolute positioned elements, width="100%" seems to be interpreted as 100% of the closest parent up the DOM tree.

position:absolute takes the element out of the flow, so widths of elements outside the absolute element in the DOM tree don't apply to anything under the absolute element.  Normally this is working fine, but in IE7 the width of the absolute element's *parent* leaked through as the baseline for 100% of the table width (although the DIV was fine.)